# Laravel app\Exceptions\Handler->report/render is ignored

Tags: php, laravel

Does anyone know why Laravel may be bypassing `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`? If I go to `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php` dump the exception from render method, but changing render/report methods `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` do not have any effect, even though it registered in `bootstrap/app.php.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        dd($exception);
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        dd($exception);
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are changing in this File, please share your code

Comment: And how is the exception triggered

Comment: I want to catch all exception triggered by application especially when things break, and then my plan is to send them as notification to slack channel, the problem is Handle.php seem to be ignored by application all together, only if I edit Handler.php from Illuminati